# no matching function for call to vector .. found C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have went over code about 5 times, i am learning c++ and according to me everything should work however that's not happening. Error makes no sense, i mean vector suppose to have "at" function..

I get **error**:

`In function 'void lookup(class vector<Customer,_default_alloc_template<false,0> > &, class string)': findByZipCode.cpp:30: no matching function for call to 'vector<Customer,_default_alloc_template,0> >::at (int)`

**findByZipCode.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "customer.h"

using namespace std;

Name readRestOfName(istream &in,string f) {
    string g;
    getline(in,g);
    Name abc (g,f);
    return abc;
}

Address readAddress(istream &in) {
    string street, city, state, zip;
    getline(in, street);
    getline(in, city);
    getline(in, state);
    getline(in, zip);
    Address abc (street, city, state, zip);
    return abc;
}

void lookup(vector<Customer>& v, string zip) {
    // COMPLETE
    vector <int> matches;
    cout<<v.at(2).getName()<<endl; <<<---------------error here!!!

}

int main() {
    // open customerdata file
    ifstream in("customerdata");
    vector<Customer> v;
    string f;

    while (getline(in,f)) {
        Name n = readRestOfName(in,f);
        Address a = readAddress(in);
        Customer abc(n,a);
        v.push_back(abc);
    }
    in.close();


string zip;
    while(!cin.fail()){
        cin>>zip;
        lookup(v,zip);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**customer.cpp and customer.h**

.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "customer.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string Customer::getName() {return n.getFamily() + ", " + n.getGiven();}
string Customer::getAddress() {return a.getStreet() + " " + a.getCity() + " "+ a.getState()+" "+a.getZip();}
string Customer::getZip() {return a.getZip();}
```

.h

```
#ifndef CUSTOMER_H
#define CUSTOMER_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "name.h"
#include "address.h"


class Customer {
    private:
        Name n;
        Address a;
    public:
        Customer(Name b,Address c): n(b), a(c) {}
        std::string getName();
        std::string getAddress();
        std::string getZip();
};

#endif
```

Comment: Is that the real error message?  Because there's some funny difference between `_default_alloc_template<false,0>` and `_default_alloc_template,0`

Comment: i typed it myself from cli, i couldn't copy paste it

Comment: let me try it on another computer..

Comment: Ahh, take a closer look at the error and make sure nothing is missing, then.

Comment: I am also surprised that the error says `vector` instead of `std::vector`

Comment: i moved the files over to linux and it works there, i think reason might have been that some .o files were compiled in linux and even though i was using git bash for in windows it didn't work out. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Glad it's working.  Messed up system headers are no joke.